# Python and telethon: login error UPDATE_APP_TO_LOGIN

Tags: python, authentication, telethon

since today, I'm getting this error when trying to login into my telegram account with telethon:

```
RPCError 406: UPDATE_APP_TO_LOGIN (caused by SendCodeRequest)
```

I don't see this in the official documentation, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have a look at this : https://t.me/TelethonChat/401111

Comment: This is a new bug. Please see https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/3215 for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look in the `Telethon Updates Channel`

Edit: The Patch is already released, just update your telethon like shown below

Quote:

> Telegram has started enforcing the use of 64-bit identifiers for users and chats, and the current stable version of the library does not support them yet. If you try to login, you may see UPDATE_APP_TO_LOGIN error.

Answer (score 3):

It's worked in my case,

```
pip install --upgrade telethon
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update telethon lib to version 1.24

Comment: it was not available when I asked the question