# How to fix UPDATE_APP_TO_LOGIN error in TLSharp C#

Tags: c#, telegram, tlsharp

Hi i am using [TLSharp](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp) latest version is **0.1.0.574** and when i call `var hash = await client.SendCodeRequestAsync("<my_phone>");` i got error `System.InvalidOperationException: 'UPDATE_APP_TO_LOGIN'` anyone know how to fix it

**My code**

```
TelegramClient client = new TelegramClient(appid, "apihash",null,"session",null,DataCenterIPVersion.OnlyIPv4);
await client.ConnectAsync();
var hash = await client.SendCodeRequestAsync("<my_phone>");
string code = "";
await client.SignUpAsync("<my_phone>", hash, code, "<fist_name>", "last_name");
```

Comment: That version is over a year old and the GitHub page says that project is no longer maintained.  Related: [Python and telethon: login error UPDATE_APP_TO_LOGIN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70180869/150605)

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews Are there any alternative libraries for TLSharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "UPDATE_APP_TO_LOGIN" happens because your Telegram Client/Library uses an obsolete API layer.

As stated on its project page, TLSharp is no longer maintained and will not be updated to fix this.

You should switch to [WTelegramClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WTelegramClient/) which is:

- offering up-to-date API (latest layer)
- safer (latest MTProto v2 implementation and many security checks)
- feature-complete (covers all API methods, handling of updates, multiple-DC connections)
- easy-to-use (API calls are direct methods with fully documented parameters in VS)
- designed for .NET 5.0+, but also available for .NET Standard 2.0 (.NET Framework 4.6.1+ & .NET Core 2.0+)

Available on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WTelegramClient/). ReadMe/Github [is here](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient).